# Reading from Text file and parsing to ArrayList

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist

### Solved adding `if (line.isEmpty()) continue;`

I need to read data from my text file and add this data into my ArrayList.

I see through debugger that the `String[] words` size is 1 which is `""`.
That is why I get an exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

My code is

```
List<Bill> list = new ArrayList<>();

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("bill.txt"))) {
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");
        Integer id = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
        String venName = words[1];
        Double amount = Double.parseDouble(words[2]);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(words[3]);
        BillType bt = BillType.valueOf(words[4]);
        list.add(new Bill(venName, amount, date, bt, id));
    }
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this assignment I cannot use File and Object input/output Stream.
Could you please help me fix this bug?

Comment: What does the file look like? Does it have all the things you are trying to read from it?

Comment: Check the contents of String `line`, does it contains space separated values?

Comment: Before the `split`, add a `if (line.isEmpty()) continue;`

Comment: Check `words.length == 5` before you proceed with each iteration

Comment: Are you sure of the content of your original text file? Is there perhaps a "\n" or "\r"  inserted that you can't see? You should really run a check on the size of `words` before you attempt to extract values from it with magic numbers

Answer (score 1):

You could use streams from `Java 8`. I think that using `pattern with groups` is much more clear that simple split string:

```
private static final Pattern WORDS = Pattern.compile("(?<id>\\d+)\\s+(?<name>[^\\s]+)\\s+(?<amount>[^\\s]+)\\s+(?<date>[^\\s]+)\\s+(?<type>[^\\s]+)");

public static List<Bill> readBillFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))
                .map(WORDS::matcher)
                .filter(Matcher::matches)
                .map(matcher -> {
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group("id"));
                    String venName = matcher.group("name");
                    double amount = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group("amount"));
                    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(matcher.group("date"));
                    BillType bt = BillType.valueOf(matcher.group("type"));
                    return new Bill(venName, amount, date, bt, id);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or you can just add check for `total words` to your code:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] words = line.split(" ");

    if(words.length < 5)
        continue;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Scanner class?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.time.*;

try (Scanner reader = new Scanner (new File ("bill.txt"))) {
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        reader.useDelimiter ("[ \t\n]");
        Integer id = reader.nextInt ();
        String venName = reader.next ();
        Double amount = reader.nextDouble ();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse (reader.next ());
//      Don't know about BillType class
        String bt = reader.next ();
//      Don't have Bill.class
//      list.add(new Bill (venName, amount, date, bt, id));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```